# FileInfo() type or namespace not found

Tags: epplus-4

I'm using the sample code below to create a spreadsheet using `EPPlus.dll`, but `FileInfo` is not recognized.

`EPPlus.dll` has been added as a reference via the Package Manager Console and the other objects and references such as `ExcelPackage` and `ExcelWorksheet` are correctly recognized, but `FileInfo` has the swiggly redline underneath it stating that Type or Namespace cannot be found.

Any thoughts as to why?

- .Net Framework 4
- c#

  ```
  using OfficeOpenXml;
  using (ExcelPackage xlWorkBook = new ExcelPackage())
  {
      ExcelWorksheet sheet = xlWorkBook.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");

      sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "testing";
      xlWorkBook.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"c:\myworkbook.xlsx"));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The directive "using System.IO;" is required.